# Numbering children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu component, and I want to be able to number the menu items within this component.  (Menu item numbers are then used to track the focused menu item and to respond to number keypad keystrokes.)

My current implementation looks something like this:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  numberChildren() {
    return _.chain(React.Children.toArray(this.props.children))
      .filter()
      .map((child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, {
          number: i + 1
      }))
      .value();
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="menu">{this.numberChildren()}</div>;
  }
};
```

I'm using [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement) to inject a `number` prop, and I'm using lodash's `filter` to exclude any null children.

This is enough to handle menus such as this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>Salad</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Grilled Chicken</MenuItem>
    {!this.props.isOnDiet && <MenuItem>Ice Cream</MenuItem>}
</Menu>
```

However, it fails for more complicated children:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>Salad</MenuItem>
    <SoupOfTheDayMenuItem/>
    <MenuItem>Grilled Chicken</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

`SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` is a wrapper component that returns either a single `MenuItem` (which should also be enumerated) or `null`.

Even if `SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` returns null, it's still truthy at the time lodash's `filter` is called, so it still gets number 2.

Is there a way to say "only inject this property for children that actually get rendered" or "get me the set of children that actually rendered somthing"? Or is there a better way of designing all of this?

Comment: If `SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` has some items they should be enumerated as well?

Comment: @mklimek - Yes; I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Check out my answer then. It should help you togheter with @Drew Schuster answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` is a wrapper for `MenuItem` or returns null.
So you can try to filter out those children which have `props.children` falsy which would mean `SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` returned null.

This should do the job:

```
numberChildren() {
    return _.chain(React.Children.toArray(this.props.children))
      .filter(child => child.type.displayName == 'MenuItem' || child.props.children)
      .map((child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, {
          number: i + 1
      }))
      .value();
  }
```

Comment: This works very well. Thank you. I made a couple of changes: I assume you mean `props` instead of `params`? Also, it looks like `child.type.displayName` isn't being set for my classes. (I'm not sure why.) However, even my normal menu items have children - so `.filter(child => child && child.props.children)` works well.

Comment: Of course I ment `props` - edited :) Glad it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

I obviously don't have all of the context for your application, but perhaps it would make more sense to wrap each child in a wrapping `MenuItemContainer` component that handles all the indexing and stuff, and then letting the child components just do whatever their purpose is. What I'm saying is something like

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
render() {
  return this.props.children.map((Child, i) => {
    return (
      <MenuItemContainer key={i}>
        <Child/>
      </MenuItemContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

};

Then `Child` can be a `MenuItem` or a `SoupOfTheDayMenuItem` without any problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. Even if `MenuItemContainer` handles indexing and stuff, how will it address the case where the second `Child` (for example) returns null and shouldn't be indexed? The second `MenuItemContainer` would have to know that it shouldn't be indexed and would have to communicate that to `MenuItemContainers` after it?

Comment: You're correct, @mklimek 's answer above did a better job explaining how to filter out the null elements beforehand.